# Why does ethtool on OpenWRT not recognise my LAN ports?

Tags: openwrt

I've got an OpenWRT-based computing cluster named Mixtile Cluster Box using an ethernet port for connection to the outside world. This port named `eth0` should run at 1 Gbit/sec speed (at least the doc of the cluster box tells me that) but the router tells me that it only runs at 100 Mbit/sec. After having received some advice, I'd like to dig into the config of the ethernet port by using `ethtool` 5.16, but the tool seems not to find the network interface:

```sh
mixtile@MixtileClusterBox:~$ sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
        Current message level: 0x000000ff (255)
                               drv probe link timer ifdown ifup rx_err tx_err
        Link detected: yes

mixtile@MixtileClusterBox:~$ sudo ethtool eth0.2
Settings for eth0.2:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
        Link detected: yes
```

But: The device does exist (otherwise I couldn't connect to the cluster):

```sh
mixtile@MixtileClusterBox:~$ ls /sys/class/net/
br-lan  eth0    eth0.1  eth0.2  lo      pci0

mixtile@MixtileClusterBox:~$ sudo hwinfo --network --short
network interface:                                              
  br-lan               Ethernet network interface
  eth0.2               Ethernet network interface
  eth0                 Ethernet network interface
  eth0.1               Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  pci0                 Ethernet network interface
```

…and does appear on `ethtool -i`'s output when querying the corresponding drivers:

```
mixtile@MixtileClusterBox:~$ sudo ethtool -i eth0
driver: mtk_soc_eth
version: 0.2
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 10100000.ethernet
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no

mixtile@MixtileClusterBox:~$ sudo ethtool -i eth0.2
driver: 802.1Q VLAN Support
version: 1.8
firmware-version: N/A
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: 
supports-statistics: no
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
```

On the other hand, another tool named `swinfo` does NOT find `eth0`. Don't ask me why:

```sh
mixtile@MixtileClusterBox:~$ swconfig list
Found: switch0 - mt7620
```

This is the OpenWRT version BTW:

```
Hostname         MixtileClusterBox
Model            MC-CLUSTERBOX
Architecture     MediaTek MT7620A ver:2 eco:6
Target Platform  ramips/mt7620
Firmware Version mixtile-cluster-box-v0.0.3-20230925 / LuCI openwrt-22.03
Kernel Version   5.10.161
```

Sounds quite paradox, doesn't it?

Comment: The tool `swconfig` is for switches, nothing else.

Comment: I performed `swconfig` because someone with the same issue and similar HW did it too (and failed): https://github.com/openwrt/openwrt/issues/8000

Comment: From searching around the net, it would appear that _ethtool_ support for those router SoC network interfaces is hit or miss. More "miss" though. It seems the problem is that somehow the switch is directly integrated with the SoC or something, meaning there is no real network interface.

Comment: Does this mean that the ethernet interface is in fact emulated somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the 100Mbps problem as well. There is some not yet public information that the manufacturer (Mixtile) can provide regarding the fix for this, including an estimated fix date. You can contact them at info@mixtile.com, though their response might be delayed due to the upcoming Chinese new year.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I already know that. The Mixtile guys even told me that the mysterios invisibility of the ethernet interface was not a bug, but simply normal for this type of hardware.